# how to parsing web socket response (JSON) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets

I have a task, I want to take the data through the web socket, and display them on the screen of the application. But I did not even find a normal example to do so. I will be grateful if someone helps to do it, or someone sets an example.
I have the socket web address:

```
wss: //ws-sandbox.coinapi.io/v1/
```

I also have a body that I will send to the socket to return the data:

```
{ "type": "hello", "apikey": "C4F12EA7-D405-4619-99FD-62F4B00A8111", "heartbeat": false, "subscribe_data_type": ["exrate"], "subscribe_filter_asset_id": ["BTC / USD"] }
```

Here's what comes back in the web socket:

```
{
  "time": "2022-04-28T16: 45: 31.0000000Z",
  "asset_id_base": "BTC",
  "asset_id_quote": "USD",
  "rate": 39693.575,
  "type": "exrate"
}
```

I want to display "rate" data on the screen.
I will be grateful for your help)

My code

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  WebSocketChannel channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("wss://ws-sandbox.coinapi.io/v1/");

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() {
    return MyHomePageState();
  }
}



class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:  Text("Web Socket"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Send any message to the server"),
                controller: _controller,
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: widget.channel.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : ''),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.send),
        onPressed: sendData,
      ),
    );
  }

  void sendData() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      widget.channel.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

The problem is that I return all the JSON(string). And I want to return only the data "rate"
My scrin:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you do not want to display the entire json body. So instead of using `snapshot.data` you need to parse it first.

`snapshot.data` has a dynamic type so I do not know what kind of data you are working with but if you somehow parse it to a `Map<String, dynamic>` you can just do `data['rate']`.

When using the regular `http` library you can parse a `http.Response` like this:

```
jsonDecode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

If you tell me the type of `snapshot.data` I might be able to give you more information.

---

**Edit:** I just tried your code and as suspected you are getting a String that we can parse with `jsonDecode`:

```
jsonDecode(snapshot.data)["rate"]
```

**If we apply this to your problem this should be the solution**:

Your Widget should look like this:

```
Text(getExtractedRate(snapshot))
```

The `getExtractedRate` method should looke like this:

```dart
  String getExtractedRate(AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.hasData ? '${jsonDecode(snapshot.data)["rate"]}' : '';
  }
```

Keep in mind that I am using the `dynamic` type to avoid typing conflicts. `jsonDecode` requires a String while `snapshot.data` is `Object?`. In your production code you also might want to check if the key `rate` is present before accessing it.

Comment: where do I analyze the answer ??? in what place ?.  My goal is to start coming about bitcoin through web sockets as soon as I enter the application. Thank you)

Comment: could you help me?)

Comment: @AndriiHavrylyak I have tried your code. Look at my edited answer, this should solve your problem. We can import `jsonEncode` and use this to parse your JSON.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check and let you know about the result)

Comment: thank you, everything is fine, everything works as it should, but there are still questions when I use "time" with JSON, everything works as it should, but the problem is in the data template, can I somehow bring the data to this form "2022-04-28T16 : 45: 31,0000000Z "to" 2022-04-28 16:45:31 "?? Thanks for the help)